# cURL request works in terminal, but when running the request in PHP I get errors

Tags: php, curl

I'm using [namechk.com](http://namechk.com) API to check if a social media name is available (Twitter). It works fine when I make a cURL request in the terminal, but when running in PHP I get errors.

The following query in the terminal works fine:

`curl -i -H "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer xxxxxxxxxx" -H "Accept: application/vnd.api.v1+json" -d "site=twitter&username=namechk" "https://api.namechk.com/services/check.json"`

Following the docs on namechk.com the following should work (unmodified, taken straight from docs):

```
<?php

$http_options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode(array('site' => 'twitter', 'username' => 'namechk')),
        'header' => array("AUTHORIZATION: Bearer xxxxxxx".PHP_EOL,    "Accept: application/vnd.api.v1+json".PHP_EOL, "Content-Type: application/json".PHP_EOL)
));

$context = stream_context_create($http_options);
$contents = file_get_contents("https://api.namechk.com/services/check.json", false, $context);
$results = json_decode($contents, true);
```

... Except I get an error:

`Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.namechk.com/services/check.json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

I write a function using cURL for PHP that returns empty:

```
public function checkSite($username, $service) {
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.namechk.com/services/check.json');

    $headers = array(
        "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer {$this->token}",
        "Accept: application/vnd.api.v1+json",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch , array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'site' => $service,
            'username' => $username
        ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
    ));

    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: 404 error means that the URL is wrong.

Comment: Are you using post method in curl, or get? Check your URL and form submission in both prior to posting.

Comment: @Barmar I know this. But as you can see from the cURL request in the terminal, and the request in PHP both URL's are the same. The URL isn't wrong, that's the problem.

Comment: Your terminal command doesn't use `-L`, which is the equivalent of `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true`.

Comment: So I suspect it's sending a redirect, and the 404 error comes from the redirect URL.

Comment: I removed the follow redirect and still facing the same issues. Also the `file_get_contents` method doesn't use any follow redirect. Both fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

The problem was that in the headers array the API documentation has `PHP_EOL` appended to each element. Remove this and it works.

Comment: `array("AUTHORIZATION: Bearer xxxxxxx".PHP_EOL...`

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the curl code, not the file_get_contents part of the question.